# Connection between Hidden Markov models and logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, hidden-markov-model, intuition

This question is inspired by a comment below this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156814/hmm-as-a-classification-tool) on Hidden Markov models: "Have you considered logistic regression? For non longitudinal data, they are practically the same thing."

**My question**
What is the *exact* connection between Hidden Markov Models and logistic regression? How can this connection be shown (perhaps also intuitively)? And when to use which and why?

Comment: Is there an 'exact' (and trivial) connection for sure? HMMs model the joint distribution between the latent states and the observation sequence, whereas logistic regression models the conditional distribution?

Comment: @AdamO: Perhaps you might want to take a shot at it?